# @Ngrx/Store with builder pattern

Tags: angular, typescript, builder, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a small doubt.... My doubt is that is it Ok or super cool or not good? To use a builder pattern for getting the response from an api and using builder pattern on that response and store that to @ngrx/store ? Then when I access it from the store in my components, I can access the functions implemented on the api response from the builder object?

I want some feedback on this... Or am I just exajerating on this... Or is it a good way of implementing the builder pattern with @ngrx/store?

Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with this (other than trading memory usage vs convenience of having class instances straight away, if that's what you fancy).

But you need to keep in mind that these Object must stay immutable.
They have to be stateless.
Their functions may not modify their own data.

You basically lose all benefits of having object instances (no more state, just a collection of functions attached to read only data).
Therefore the functions on the objects themselves might aswell be external functions that operate with your store data as input instead.

Or you create the object instances later based on the data (but need to make sure no reference to the store data is being modified).

Comment: I experimented with It.... And It seems the whole point of using class is lost.... If I wouldnt use the object to modify the data.... Then there is no need to use it.... Correct me if iam wrong... Or does it seem advantageous to you...